# How do I save a List of objects in a UWP app using C#?

Tags: c#, list, object, uwp

I have a list of objects that I want to be saved when the user closes the application.  I know how to save a list of strings using Newtonsoft.Json, and I know how to save integer and string variables using composite.  But how do I save a list of objects?

Comment: It would same as serializing list of strings. JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list of objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConvert` to convert the list to a JSON string and save it locally.

```cs
public async Task SaveList(List<TestModel> list)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var saveFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("SaveList.json", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(saveFile, json);
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: That's helpful, but how would I read the saved objects back and add them to the list again?

Comment: You can deserialize the text by calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestModel>>(jsonString)` to get the List.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `List` into json string, and save it in a txt file.

You can use `DataContractJsonSerializer` to parse to whatever type you want.
Make sure your json string is in right formate.

here is an example

```
public static object PrepareObjectFromString<T>(string json)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var deSerializedUser = dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            return deSerializedUser;
        }
    }
```

And you can convert your json to a list of objects like this

```
List<MyModelObject> listOfObject=  PrepareObjectFromString<List<Session>(jsonString);
```

You can convert it back like this

```
public static string PrepareJsonString<T>(object objectToBeParsed)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            string json = string.Empty;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(ms, (T)objectToBeParsed);
                ms.Position = 0;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return json;
        }
```

here is the converting line

```
string json= PrepareJsonString<List<Events>>(listOfObjects);
```

Hope this helps.